# Gerrit version 2.14.4 online reindexing stuck

Tags: gerrit

How do i know that online reindexing is done ?

I had a repository with name datadelivery-feed-tcp-c++ which I moved to datadelivery-feed-tcp-cpp and deleted the datadelivery-feed-tcp-c++ repository.

But On kicking online reindexing it gives a lot of below warning.It is stuck at this warning.

```
[2017-09-28 07:00:27,300] [Index-Batch-3] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.index.change.StalenessChecker : error checking staleness of 8737 in datadelivery-feed-tcp-c%252B%252B
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: Invalid name: datadelivery-feed-tcp-c%252B%252B
```

I have tried flushing cache also 
ssh -p 29418 host gerrit flush-caches --all

How do I resolve it ?

EDIT : By renaming a repo I meant, I have cloned it and imported all the data into other project, verified it and then removed it using delete project plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think you already had changes in the datadelivery-feed-tcp-c++ repository and you just renamed it at the filesystem, correct? You can't do that because you need to adjust the database data accordingly. The better way to rename a repository is doing the following:

1) Clone the original repository (with all existing changes) creating a new one with the new name. Use the [importer plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/importer/+/refs/heads/master) to do that.

2) Remove the original repository (and all related changes). Use the [delete-project](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/delete-project/+/refs/heads/master) plugin to do that.

Notes:

i) In your current case, first rename the repository back to the original name at the filesystem.

ii) You can download the plugins [here](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/).

Comment: No, I didn't just rename it on the disk.I properly moved all the content of this repo into another.

One question: If I am deleting original reposiotory, do i have to delete its chnages also ? Can't I update changes in database to point to new repo ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I properly moved all the content of this repo into another"? Did you change the database accordingly? What was your exact procedure?